#  is there a browser-addon that can create a temporary txt file from my clipboard and populate the file submit dialog?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

I would like to upload XML and diff reports into jira tickets as file attachments rather than inline text.
Jira has an image uploader as an attachment.

To clarify the question with a scenario -
I have a log/xml/txt fragment I copied onto the clipboard.
I can either paste it as a comment into a jira ticket
Or
I can open notepad then paste/save/name a file then upload/attach the file to a ticket.

To rephrase my question - is there a browser-addon that can create a temporary txt file from my clipboard and populate the file submit dialog?

Comment: To clarify, you want this solved through browser or OS functionality, not by enhancing Jira?

Comment: If your asking is there a way to upload the contents of the clipboard, the answer is: it depends, its unlikely Jira will have this ability.  Its strange Jira doesn't have the ability to add attachments, other the images, you sure there isn't an exntension that provides that?

Comment: My instance of jira has this as built-in functionality. What version are you using?